# Hover on a div, in a div with hover

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have a div enclose in another div. Two of them have an hover effect. Is it possible to unactive parent div hover effect when i'm on the other div ?

Exemple here : when my mouse in on the blue div, i want to cancel hover in the red div without change on my hierarchy.

http://jsfiddle.net/ynj9t2kf/

```
.div1:hover{
    background:yellow;
}
.div2:hover{
    background:green;
}
```

Comment: With CSS alone, and not changing the hierarchy, you can't. If you can change the hierarchy, you can do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/75ovqsgd/

Comment: Thanks ! But i can't change the hierarchy here, i thought it was possible to do it with CSS alone :/

Comment: You said you can't change the hierarchy but you accepted the answer that requires that you add another element? OK. Well, if you want a jQuery answer here's one http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ynj9t2kf/22/

Comment: Ok sorry, didn't mean to accept the wrong answer, but i thought no one will answer a jQuery solution. Btw, ty you for your anwser j08691 !

Comment: If it works for you then it's not the wrong answer, but you might want to edit the question to remove the can't change the hierarchy restriction. And if you decide to go the jQuery route let me know and I'll post my comment as an answer.

Comment: Ok, then answer and I pick you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no clean CSS-only way to do this. If you desire a jQuery method you could do it this way:

```js
$('.div2').hover(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    $(this).addClass('green')
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass('green')
})
$('.div1').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('yellow')
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('yellow')
})
```

```css
.div1 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
}
.div2 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.yellow {
    background:yellow;
}
.green {
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no parent selector in CSS, you could use a workaround and apply a red outline to the `.div2` when hovered and set an `overflow: hidden` to `.div1`, e.g.

```
.div1 {
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
}

.div2 {
   ...
}

.div1:hover{
   ...
}

.div2:hover {
    ...
    outline: 999em red solid ;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/924zuneu/

With this approach when you hover `.div2` the outer div still applies a yellow background, but the outline will cover it.

---

Another approach is to style a pseudoelement of `.div2`, e.g.

```
.div1 {
    ...
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.div2 {
   ...
}

.div1:hover {
   ...
}

.div2:hover{
   ...
}

.div2:hover:before {
   content    : "";
   background : red;
   position   : absolute;
   z-index    : -1;
   pointer-events: none;
   top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

Here `pointer-events` is needed otherwise when you leave the `.div2` you wouldn't see the hover effect for `.div1`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kr4453bj/3/

---

Result (for both methods)

when `.div1` is hovered

[image]

when `.div2` is hovered

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the little trick, but i was looking for a cleaner method ... By the way if this is not possible with CSS, I'll do it with JQuery

Comment: so you may add `jQuery` tag to your question. Anyway unless you have specific reason to use a js approach don't discard at all a pure css workaround like this.

Answer (score -1):

May be useful for you

```
.div1 {
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color:red;
}
.div2 {
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:blue;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
}
.div1:hover {
background:yellow;
}
.div2:hover {
background:green;
}
body {
margin:0;
}
```